# How Can I inject Java Code in Android Application to Read Application Specific Files using frida?

Tags: java, android, frida

I want to read an Application Specific file stored in /data/data/package_name location for X package, I've found that Android JAVA provides functionalities to read Application Specific directories and files (refer [doc)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), so I was thinking can I inject JAVA code using frida to retrieve/read file contents ([example](https://frida.re/docs/examples/android/))? I don't have root access on my device.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have root access on your phone you can not use Frida to hook arbitrary apps. Frida requires frida-server which has to be started with root permissions to be able to inject code into apps.

But on a rooted device you can simply execute `su` and directly get access to the app-private file in `/data/data/<package name>/`.

The only way to inject code into an app on a non-rooted device is to modify the APK files before installation and inject frida-gdget-server into the app and force it to be executed when the app starts.

After modifying the APK you have to re-sign it with a different signature so the app can not be installed as update to the original unmodified app because of the different signature.

But if you have already modified the app you could have also modified the debuggable flag to give you full access using `run-as` via adb.

**Conclusion: No matter what you do using Frida to get access to app-private files does not make sense.**